# Attach a string to every group of substrings separated by a set of symbols

Tags: regex, matlab

Imagine I have string

```
Newton = 'kg*m/s^2'
```

and I need it to be:

```
NewtonMupad = 'unit::kg*unit::m/unit::s^2'
```

**Is there a simple way to detect every physical unit and attach `unit::` to it?** It can be assumed every unit is seperated by either `/`, `*` or an exponent `^2` or `^3`.

For now I used several regular expressions, like

```
x = regexp(Newton ,'*','split')
y = regexp(Newton ,'/','split')
z = regexp(Newton ,'^','split')
```

and I'm able to create the string I need with a loop. But I wonder if there is any simpler and faster solution using Matlab?

Comment: Is it ok if, rather than detecting /, * or ^2/^3, it detects all the non-letters?

Comment: but how would you differ between them? `^` needs a different handling than, `/` and `*` - and as just these three can appear, I think m.s.'s solution is quite neat.

Comment: Was thinking of using regexprep, but m.s. answered before me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`regexprep`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
>> Newton = 'kg*m/s^2'
>> regexprep(Newton,'(([a-zA-Z]+)(*|/|\^|$))', 'unit::$1')

ans = 

unit::kg*unit::m/unit::s^2
```

Comment: I think there is something missing, e.g. `'A/m'` does not work. But I don't understand enough of your regex, to fix it myself. The three math operators in the example are not necessarily there.